# Add MSI package as a resource in .net project

Tags: .net, installation, windows-installer, setup-project

Is there any way to add an msi setup file as a resource to a simple .net project? Or should I go for a different installer for achieving this?

Comment: Yes, you can add .msi, just like any other file type, as a (binary) resource to a Windows executable. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov: I trying to add multiple MSI setup files to my .net project (which works as an installer). Is it necessary to add the setup.exe file along with the corresponding msi file?

Comment: You surely need a way to start the installation, `Setup.exe` is the recommended way to do it. If you write your installer in .Net, it surely requires .Net to be installed, which might be not installed on user's computer.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov: As part of mandatory pre-requisites, my users should have .net 4 installed. So that should not be a problem. If I have 2 packages say: "FirstPackage.msi, setup.exe" and "SecondPackage.msi, setup.exe", can I all the 4 files into the resources?

Comment: Of course you can. Since you packing MSIs, you don't need setup.exe to start installing .msi file. If the package itself has setup.exe, then most probably it won't work if launched not from setup.exe.

Comment: Hi guys, I am facing a similar doubt. Is there any way to include a .msi file as a resource in a .net project? If so, how I could make this happens? My application should allow to install a package using a .msi file. I am not sure if a .msi file can be added as binary resource.